# Switching between pages causes crashes on Windows 10 Mobile

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

I'm using Xamarin Forms (2.3.4.247) and my application is using "HamburgerMenu". To switch between pages i'm using it's code:

```
private FirstPage firstPage; //it's i get from the constructor
private SecondPage secondPage = new SecondPage();
private ThirdPage thirdPage = new ThirdPage(); 
private async void ItemSelectedMethod()
{
        var root = App.NavigationPage.Navigation.NavigationStack[0];
        if (SelectedItem == Items[0])
        {
            if (!IsFirstChoose)
            {
                App.NavigationPage.Navigation.InsertPageBefore(firstPage, root);
                await App.NavigationPage.PopToRootAsync(false);
            }
        }
        if (SelectedItem == Items[1])
        {
            App.NavigationPage.Navigation.InsertPageBefore(secondPage, root);
            await App.NavigationPage.PopToRootAsync(false);
        }
        if (SelectedItem == Items[2])
        {
            App.NavigationPage.Navigation.InsertPageBefore(thirdPage, root);
            await App.NavigationPage.PopToRootAsync(false);
        }

        IsFirstChoose = false;
        rootPageViewModel.IsPresented = false;
}
```

All working good on Android and Windows 10 desktop, on Windows 10 Mobile simulator my app crashes when I switch between thirdPage and firstPage.
FirstPage is root:

```
FirstPage firstPage = new FirstPage();
NavigationPage = new NavigationPage(firstPage);
```

I don't know why... Simulator don't allow debugging...

The second thing:
When I update Xamarin Forms to version 2.3.5.256-pre6 my app throw exception "System.ArgumentException: 'Cannot insert page which is already in the navigation stack'"... But when I change code to:

```
App.NavigationPage.Navigation.InsertPageBefore(new ThirdPage(), root);
App.NavigationPage.Navigation.InsertPageBefore(new SecondPage(), root);
//etc
```

all working... 
Does anyone know why this is happening? I don't want create new objects when pages is switch...

Answer (score 0):

You have answered the question so I can only confirm this:

```
System.ArgumentException: 'Cannot insert page which is already in the navigation stack'
```

As you can see, you already have the page firstPage in `App.NavigationPage.Navigation` so inserting another one makes the app crash. You just can't do it as you have explained - either you have to create a new instance or you have to remove previous instance from the stack.

Comment: Yes, but why it's not throwing on version 2.3.4.247? And why app crashed only on Win10Mobile?

Comment: Xamarin is transforming your calls to native classes. Each OS has its native classes that support navigation and they might act different. It obviously doesn't work on Windows 10 Mobile. Why it is not thrown in the previous version of Xamarin? Probably because something wasn't working as it should that's one of the reasons why there are Xamarin updates.

Comment: You're probably right. So... What code should be to working on Android and Windows Mobile? (now me code working only on Android and Windows desktop).

Comment: As said if you don't want to create a new instance you can check if the current instance is present in the stack and remove it.