# How to switch between pages with Xamarin.Forms.INavigation.InsertPageBefore

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm using Xamarin Forms and I'm having an issue use InsertPageBefore() method with existing objects of Pages.

Here is my view code:

```
private FirstPage firstPage; 
private SecondPage secondPage = new SecondPage();
private ThirdPage thirdPage = new ThirdPage(); 
private async void ItemSelectedMethod()
{
        var root = App.NavigationPage.Navigation.NavigationStack[0];
        if (SelectedItem == Items[0])
        {
            if (!IsFirstChoose)
            {
                App.NavigationPage.Navigation.InsertPageBefore(firstPage, root);
                await App.NavigationPage.PopToRootAsync(false);
            }
        }
        if (SelectedItem == Items[1])
        {
            App.NavigationPage.Navigation.InsertPageBefore(secondPage, root);
            await App.NavigationPage.PopToRootAsync(false);
        }
        if (SelectedItem == Items[2])
        {
            App.NavigationPage.Navigation.InsertPageBefore(thirdPage, root);
            await App.NavigationPage.PopToRootAsync(false);
        }

        IsFirstChoose = false;
        rootPageViewModel.IsPresented = false;
}
```

It's throw exception "System.ArgumentException: 'Cannot insert page which is already in the navigation stack'". How to switch between existing objects of pages? I don't want create new object in InsertPageBefore(). I tried use it code, before call InsertPageBefore():

```
foreach (var item in App.NavigationPage.Navigation.NavigationStack.ToList())
                App.NavigationPage.Navigation.RemovePage(item);
```

But it's not working... Can anyone help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44865472/switching-between-pages-causes-crashes-on-windows-10-mobile  What are you trying to achieve? Why you are using Insert and Pop instead of Push?

Comment: I want it's menu: https://csharp-dev.pl/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/5.png
When I click on item, his page is showing as "root page".

Comment: looks like you are using master/detail page. Is your NavigationPage in details?

Comment: Yes. rootPage.Detail = NavigationPage;
It's code working on older version of Xamarin with Android, but don't work on new version of Xamain and on Windows 10 Mobile.

Comment: When I use this line: App.NavigationPage.Navigation.InsertPageBefore(new ThirdPage(), root); all is ok, but I don't want create new object in args for this method (InsertPageBefore).

Comment: I still think that you should consider better design. May be I am wrong but your design doesn't feel right, sorry. You are trying to put to stack the page you already have. If you do "new" then it is another Page3 created and you don't have a problem but that is probably not what you want. You should check if Page3 is already on stack and Pop to it.

Comment: But Page3 isn't on stack when I first call method InsertPageBefore(thirdPage, root) or I'm wrong?

Comment: Then use Push why InsertBefore?

Comment: App.NavigationPage.Navigation.PushAsync(thirdPage); throw exception System.InvalidOperationException: 'Page must not already have a parent.'

Comment: When I first call InsertPageBefore(thirdPage, root) app throw exception "System.ArgumentException: 'Cannot insert page which is already in the navigation stack'", but third page is not on stack... It's the first call...

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do and possibly share the project

Comment: It's sample project: http://www75.zippyshare.com/v/BjXfVOjb/file.html (with Xamarin 2.3.5.256-pre6)

Comment: great, can you explain your desired flow? what should I press and what should happen

Comment: I want it's working ;) When you click first item on menu -> load first page, when click second item - load second page etc...
I don't want back button, when user go to other page than mainPage. Current page is "root page". As I wrote it's project working with older Xamarin version on Android.

Comment: Couple things. 1. You have different versions of Forms in different projects, that's not good. When I consolidated everything to last released version 247 everything works. Try that. 2. You are using MasterDetail page. From what I see you don't need Navigation page at all. I suggest you to read more how to implement MasterDetai page correctly

Comment: void OnItemSelected (object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = e.SelectedItem as MasterPageItem;
        if (item != null) {
            Detail = new NavigationPage ((Page)Activator.CreateInstance (item.TargetType));
            masterPage.ListView.SelectedItem = null;
            IsPresented = false;
        }
    }

Comment: 1. Yes, but I tested it sample only on Windows 10 ;) All works ok with version 247, but not with 2.3.5.256 - can you try it? I need this version, because 247 has bug https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=56164 . I need patch from 256 in my project. 2. What did I do wrong?

Comment: What you want me to try? All projects with 256? 2. See my comments what should have in OnItemSelected if you implement MasterDetail correctly. Read more about it

Comment: 1. Yes, I want you try 256 2. Ok I read more about it, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It didn't work with UWP. Here is agly workaround for you but you really need to read how to work with Master-Detail pages.

```
public partial class App : Application
    {
        public static RootPage RootPage { get; private set; } //DON'T DO THIS, 
                                                              //FIND A BETTER WAY 
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            RootPage = new RootPage();
            MenuPage menuPage = new MenuPage(RootPage.vm);

            RootPage.Master = menuPage;
            RootPage.Detail = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());// NavigationPage;
            MainPage = RootPage;
        }

        protected override void OnStart()
        {
            // Handle when your app starts
        }

        protected override void OnSleep()
        {
            // Handle when your app sleeps
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            // Handle when your app resumes
        }
    }
```

Then

```
private async void ItemSelectedMethod()
        {

            if (SelectedItem == Items[0])
            {
                App.RootPage.Detail = new NavigationPage(mainPage);
            }
            if (SelectedItem == Items[1])
            {
                App.RootPage.Detail = new NavigationPage(secondPage);
            }
            if (SelectedItem == Items[2])
            {
                App.RootPage.Detail = new NavigationPage(thirdPage);
            }
            rootPageViewModel.IsPresented = false;
        }
```

Comment: It's working! Thank you very much for help! (considering my English) :)

Comment: You are welcome but don't use it as it is :-) Please read how to do it better

Comment: PS: Why I shouldn't use static RootPage?

Comment: It's not a good idea in general to use static variables. You can find many posts why it's bad.

Comment: Sometimes they are useful, but I will look for another way :) Thank you again :)

Comment: It's better solution?
MenuPage menuPage = new MenuPage(RootPage);
Then in MenuPageViewModel I can:
private RootPage rootPage;
 public MenuPageViewModel(RootPage rootPage)
 {
this.rootPage = rootPage;
}
and use this object in ItemSelectedMethod().

Comment: Ohh... I understand now how to do right. I must add TargetType to class MenuItem :)
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/navigation/master-detail-page/

Comment: I should try write it with MVVM or code-behind (as in sample)?

Comment: MVVM will be more complicated as you need to pass your view to your model to be able to navigate from there. It can create a circular model-view dependence. Make sure you set to null your model which you probably create in view when view is destroyed. Some people don't like to navigate from code behind and insist on navigation from model. I personally don't see anything terrible to navigate from code behind

Comment: Okay, I think waste of time for MVVM here. The code will not be better or more readable ;)

Comment: I have one more question. Does this implementation create new page objects when i choose item or use one instance ever?

Comment: In solution you used (and I didn't modify the approach) Master and Details pages are created only once. In the approach Xamarin suggests the Detail pages are created every time you select a new item in master page using CreateInstance. If you need to keep an instance, use your approach, if you want a new page you can use either CreateInstance or just if/else as in the answer but do App.RootPage.Detail = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());